# UIImagePickerController does nothing when using camera after I hit "Use" button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Code below.

When I hit the "Use" button after taking a picture ... the application becomes totally unresponsive.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  The "addPlayer:" method is called when a button is pressed on the UIViewController's view.

Thanks

```
- (IBAction) addPlayers: (id)sender{
    // Show ImagePicker
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    // If camera is available use it and display custom overlay view so that user can add as many pics
    // as they want without having to go back to parent view
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    } 
    else {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    // Grab original image
    UIImage *photo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Resize photo first to reduce memory consumption
    [self.photos addObject:[photo scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(200.0f, 300.0f)]];

    // Enable *PLAY* button if photos > 1
    if([self.photos count] > 1) btnStartGame.enabled = YES;

    // Update player count label
    lblPlayerCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.photos count]];

    // Dismiss picker if not using camera
    picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Which method does your "Use" button call?

Comment: The "Use" button (from the built in camera controls) calls the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method above.  

I was able to get this working but ONLY after moving the "[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];" line to the top of the same method.  However, still seems a bit slugglish.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem today. The problem was that I was over-releasing the variable. Here's the part of my code that was crashing:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init]autorelease];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]
```

and then:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  UIImage *image = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]fixOrientation];
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(uploadAPhoto:) withObject:image];

  [picker release];
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

the only thing I did is deleting the 
[picker release];
line and now it works just fine.

Looking at your code I'd say that there's a problem with this line:

```
picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

if that's how it is in your project, then it's really strange that it even runs, there's missing '[' at the beginning of the line. And I'm using

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Try using that.

**Edit**

Sorry, didn't see the date of the question :)

Comment: If OP were missing that bracket in their project, it wouldn't even compile.